# value part of key value pair not accesible in ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs

I have the below  HTML code with AngularJS

```
<div class="col-xs-1" style="width:130pt;background-color:#474747;border:2px ridge;">
    <div class="container-fluid"> 
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="dropdown" style="width:140px;" ng-repeat = "page in homeCategoryList">
                <a class= "dropdown-toggle dropdown-menu-hover-color menu-left-color" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" ng-repeat ="(key, value) in page">{{key}}</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="position:absolute;float:right;top: 0; left: 140px;">
                    <li ng-repeat = "subcat in value">
                        <a class="dropdown-level1-color " href= "#" ng-repeat="(key,value) in subcat">{{key}}</a>
                        <ul type="none">
                          <li ng-repeat="childcat in value"><a href="3">{{childcat}}}</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to represent the below JSON in the above html using angularjs. The problem is that I am able to access "electronics" but not its value which is an array."li ng-repeat="subcat in {{value}}" gives error Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'value' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 3 of the expression [{{value}}] starting at [value}}].

```
[
    {
        "electronics": [
            {
                "cameras": [
                    "sony",
                    "panasonic",
                    "nikon",
                    "canon"
                ]
            },
            {
                "TV": "none"
            },
            {
                "laptop": [
                    "toshiba",
                    "hp",
                    "apple",
                    "samsung",
                    "sony",
                    "acer",
                    "lenovo"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "home": [
            {
                "furniture": [
                    "cupboard",
                    "table",
                    "chair"
                ]
            },
            {
                "couch": "none"
            },
            {
                "utensils": "none"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Could anyone kindly tell me how to access the value variable in the ng-repeat.

Comment: At first glance, I believe it has to with the fact that you're referencing value as {{value}} but if you would put together a fiddle it would assist us in helping

Comment: @Brocco: This is just a part of a huge code,so creating a fiddle out of it would be  difficult. Its just that I want to access the value variable  which is in the ul(with ng-repeat="(key,value) in page") tag.

Comment: Shouldn't this `<li ng-repeat="subcat in {{value}}">` look like this: `<li ng-repeat="subcat in value">`?

Comment: I did try that but i think the value variable is not accessible there ,since "cameras" is not there in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to re-do your HTML/classes but take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/Fs8eH/

You might want to consider using a tree directive if the layers get any deeper.

```
<ul ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <li style="width:140px;" ng-repeat="page in homeCategoryList">
        <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in page"> <span>{{key}}</span>

            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="item in value">
                    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in item"> <span>{{key}}</span>

                        <ul>
                            <li ng-repeat="brand in value"> <span>{{brand}}
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I was just in the process of writing up nearly an identical fiddle. Looks good.

Comment: @EnigmaRM Thanks, although not fun to keep track of the nesting, but it should be dynamic enough to satisfy the requirements

Comment: @Brocco : I have edited the Angularjs code in the question,could you kindly tell me why won't that work. Your code doesn't work as well in my case(I need the exact same structure with anchor tags)

Comment: @Brocco Just a headsup the ng-app and ng-controller are all there in the rest of the code and that's functioning properly.

Comment: @Brocco I modified that according to your solution and it worked. Thanks for the help.